# Assign temporary CSS class to the DOM element that corresponds, via the use of ngRepeat, a newly added array element

Tags: css, angularjs

The code below presents an array of locations in an unordered list via the use of `ngRepeat`.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="loc in locList track by loc.id">{{loc.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

User is given the functionality to add more locations to the list, one at a time. I want to be able to assign a temporary CSS class to the `<li>` element that corresponds to the newly added location to the array. The CSS class is used to indicate the newly added element to the user by changing the background colour of the element and thus the CSS class would last for about one second. I can't think of any way to achieve this with AngularJS. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a class to an element just added to an ngRepeat list, then you can define a custom animation. Even though you haven't asked to perform a transition, an animation provides the hooks to react to an item being added to such a list (among other things). What you need is the "enter" animation. Say you have a class on each item, `my-list-item`

```
<li class="my-list-item" ng-repeat="item in chosenItems track by item.id">{{item.name}}</li>
```

Then you can define an `enter` animation on `.my-list-item`. All this does is add a class, in this case `just-added`, and then a second later, removes it.

```
app.animation('.my-list-item', function($timeout) {
  return {
    enter : function(element, done) {
      element.addClass('just-added');
      $timeout(function() {
        element.removeClass('just-added');
        done();
      },1000);
    }
  };
});
```

Angular notices when you add an item with a class `my-list-item`, and then runs the `enter` animation. You can see this in action at in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/g94btxVRYgBwZUCY9GTn?p=preview). You can also [read up on Angular animations](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#how-to-make-animations-in-angularjs). You need to include the ngAnimate module for this to work.

If you don't need to actually add a class, and only want the CSS to change, and are targeting browsers that support it, it might be better to use CSS transitions/transforms/animations/keyframe animations.

Comment: Is there a way to skip the animation for the initial set of items (ie. ones that are initialized in the controller) with your approach?

Comment: I've [created a new Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qhqhK446I5we9Iz2GXYq?p=preview) with the same custom animation, with items initialised in the controller that don't show the red background on the initial elements. Is your case different? (If so, can you create a Plunker that shows it?)

Comment: Michal - Yes, that's exactly what I am looking for. I assumed your solution would also apply the animation on the items initialized in the controller, like artworkad's solution. I should have tried your solution, not just making assumption, before I bugged you again. My apology. Thanks for your help and I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YbUkQ/3/)</kbd>

This is not really related to angular but to css animations. However here is a working example

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [];

    $scope.addItem = function(){
        $scope.list.push({ name: 'item#' + $scope.list.length });
    };
}
```

HTML;

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="addItem()">Add item</button>
    <ul>
        <li class="anim" ng-repeat="item in list">{{ item.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
   from {background: red;}
   to {background: none;}
}

.anim {
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s;
}
```

Every item is animated on creation. The color fades from red to none to indicate the latest item.

Comment: Ah~I see. I have played with only CSS transitions, but not CSS animations. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Is there a way to skip the animation for the initial set of items (ie. ones that are initialized in the controller) with your solution?

Comment: @tamakisquare http://jsfiddle.net/Jfhr3/ I think using timeouts for this is not necessary since we have css animations.

Answer (score 0):

as I'm not a fan of CSS animation for this kind of use, I made you this little fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/FhDY8/1/
It's based simply on a scope variable and the $timeout service called when you add a new item (I assumed you called a function in the controller for that)
On the HTML side I added a ng-class property, based on a newly created variable

```
<li ng-class='{last:lastInserted==loc.name}' ng-repeat="loc in locList track by loc.id">{{loc.name}}</li>
```

On the controller side I made this, the important part is the function called in the $timeout

```
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout){
   $scope.locList=[{id:1,name:"loc1"},{id:2,name:"loc2"},{id:3,name:"loc3"},{id:4,name:"loc4"}]
   $scope.lastInserted="";
   $scope.addLoc=function(){
       $scope.locList.push({id:$scope.locList.length+1,name:$scope.newLoc});   
       $scope.lastInserted=$scope.newLoc;
       $scope.newLoc="";
       $timeout(function(){
                $scope.lastInserted="";
            }, 2000)
   }
});
```

When you click to add an item to your list, the name is copied to the variable used in the ng-class, which makes the class active for the last item you inserted. At this moment, I delay an action (with $timeout) which will simply change the value in the ng-class comparison, so angular will automatically remove the class, which will stay only during the little delay (in my example 2 seconds)

Hope it helps a little

Have fun

Comment: Interesting solution. Your solution has made the assumption that new element is added to the end of the array, which isn't true in my case.

Comment: In the example it's added to the end, but you can insert it where you want, it only relies on the name (but it can be changed with any other property quite quickly), here is an example where the item is added at the index 2 in the array : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/FhDY8/2/

Comment: Adding this functionality to the `$scope` seems like a mixing of concerns between business and view logic.

Comment: @MichalCharemza could you develop your point a bit more ? How would you achieve this otherwise ?

Comment: I would either use my own answer, or something like @artworklad's. Both of them don't pollute the controller with logic that is purely for view purposes. The usual recommendations for Angular is that each bit of code has a clearly defined purpose, and that code to do with the model (say, adding an item to a list), is fairly ignorant of how it's displayed, so it remains concise, it can be easily tested, and how its displayed easily changed. The [Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) state that the controller should contain business logic, but a search should find more.

Comment: @MichalCharemza ok, but let's say I want to be ie7 compatible, or I don't want to overcharge my client browser with animations, or maybe I'm stubborn, and I want to implement exactly this behavior but in your super clean angular way, how would I achieve this ? I'm not stating that this solution is better, but I'd like to know how you would do. If we're really splitting hair, I think you could make 3 functions, one called by the ng-click, which will call the code bound to the model (add the item) and the last one to call the timeout. It complies with your definition, but doesn't change anything

Comment: @DotDotDot This might be getting a bit off topic for this question. Maybe post this as a question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, where you can also attract others' opinions. It would be helpful to clarify exactly what behaviour you're wanting to keep that is different to the other answers here, as I'm not sure on that.